# use setter/getter to get/update value

Tags: javascript

I have an object with a method `path`. When the method is executed without parameters, I want it to act like a getter, when with parameter - act like a setter. How can I do that using js getters/setters? This option seems wrong:

```
var o = {
  get path(p) {
     if (p === undefined) {
        return _path;
     } else {
        return _path=p;
     }
  }
}
```

If I define an object like that:

```
var o = {
  get path() {
    return _path;
  }
  set path() {
    _path=p;
  }
}
```

And then set it like that `o.path("some")`, the browser (Chrome) executes the getter and then throws `o.path is not a function`

Comment: @apsillers, what's wrong with the syntax. I updated the code

Comment: Are you trying to have `set` logic inside your `get`?

Comment: @MinusFour, no, that's the solution that is obvious, but seems wrong. I was wondering how getters/setters are used when the method with the same name should act as both setter and a getter

Comment: You can have both a setter and a getter for the same property. That doesn't mean you have to mesh the logic inside just one. Also notice, getters can't have arguments.

Comment: @apsillers, thanks, the concern is using this aproach that the getter changes object state

Comment: @MinusFour, my browser tells me that I can't :(. Updated my question

Comment: Javascript (ECMAScript 5) Getters and Setters[1] are used for modifying what happens when you attempt to access or change a property, like when you say:
`console.log(myObj.foo)` or `myObj.foo = 4`. I don't believe they can be used to define what happens when you access a function. Fortunately, you can just define a function as a property of your object to solve your problem! (See Cyril's and davcs86's answers)


Footnote [1]: http://robertnyman.com/2009/05/28/getters-and-setters-with-javascript-code-samples-and-demos/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Getters and setters don't work that way. A getter will follow up a certain function logic when you simply access the property. There's no need to call a function, same thing goes with setters you don't have to call the function, you'll do so when trying to set up the property.

So getters and setters are a nice way to write:

```
o.getProp();
o.setProp(nValue);
```

To:

```
o.prop;
o.prop = nValue;
```

Don't mix setter logic with getter logic:

```js
var __path = '/';
var o = {}
Object.defineProperty(o, 'path', {
    get: function(){
     return __path;   
    },
    set: function(p){
        __path = p;
    }
});

console.log(o.path, __path);
o.path = '/home';
console.log(o.path, __path);
```

I used `Object.defineProperty` in this example, but this also seems to work:

```
var o = {
    get path(){
        return __path;
    },
    set path(n){
        __path = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a stupid mistake of mine. I know what you've laid out. I just started using getters and setters recently and occasionally call them as functions (as earlier). How does js know whether to call a getter or a setter? If there's parameters - that's a setter?

Comment: That's a very interesting question, unfortunately I don't know exactly. This is definitely worth a SO question because getters and setters can behave somewhat weird with the prototype chain. It's defined somewhere on the ES standard though.

Comment: got you, asked the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084575/how-js-differentiates-between-getters-and-setters

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
 function path(p) {
       if (p) {
          _path = p;
          return p;
       } else {
          return _path;
       }
    }
```

Comment: I think  your logic is backwards, `if (p)...` should do the setting