# How js differentiates between getters and setters

Tags: javascript

For example, I have the following:

```
var o = {
  get path() {
    return _path;
  }
  set path() {
    _path=p;
  }
}
```

And call it like that:

```
o.path // getter is called
o.path = 4 // setter is called
```

How does js know which function to call in each case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time that Javascript tries to assign or obtain a value to a property it tries to resolve the reference, checks if the reference is an object property and finally checks if it's an `accessorDescriptor`:

> An accessor property descriptor is one that includes any fields named either [[Get]] or [[Set]]

*[[Get]] not to be confused with Object's Internal Operation [[Get]] (P)*

Setters are not only called with the assignment operator:

```js
var num = 0;
var o = {
  get myNum() {
      return num;
    },
    set myNum(n) {
      num = n;
    }
}

o.myNum++;
console.log(o.myNum);

var arr = [];

var o2 = {
  get prop() {
      return arr;
    },
    set prop(p) {
      arr.push(p);
    }
}

var o3 = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 'b',
  c: 'c',
  d: 'd'
}

for (o2.prop in o3) {

}

console.log(o2.prop);
```

[[Get]] and [[Set]] Object internal operations mostly handle the `isAccessorDescriptor` logic although there are certain other abstract operations that might do these checks.

There are a bunch of places on the spec where [[Get]] (P) and [[Set]] (P, V) are being called, although you'll probably want to check on `GetValue` and `PutValue` instead. It'd be easier to remember that if you try to put a value to or get a value from an object property it will check if it has an `accessorDescriptor` and will call it's respective function.

Comment: thanks, that's not a trivial example the last one with the array. But after reading your explanation several times I still struggle to understand it. Would you bother to elaborate?

Comment: Basically every time you try to put a value inside the object property it will use the `setter` function, every time you try to get a value from an object property that has a `getter` function it will call this other function. In the last example, the `for` loop is putting all the properties of the object `o3` inside the `o2.prop` property.

Answer (score 3):

The same way that it knows if you are reading a property or writing one without an explicit getter or setting being assigned. It looks to see if there is an assignment operator or not.

Comment: yeah, that seems obvious, thanks,  I just got confused with these getters/setters

Answer (score 1):

From the docs ([set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) and [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get)):

setters:

> **It must have exactly one parameter** (see Incompatible ES5 change: literal getter and setter functions must now have exactly zero or one arguments for more information);

getters:

> **It must have exactly zero parameters** (see Incompatible ES5 change: literal getter and setter functions must now have exactly zero or one arguments for more information);

For a deeper understanding, the two documentation links really do the job!

Comment: thanks, so is it parameters count or an assignment operator?

Comment: I belive it's the assignment operator that does the actual setting. The param count is more like a validation (to check if indeed it needs to call a `PutValue`):  http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.13.1

Comment: That's a description of what a getter and setter function must look like, not how JavaScript determines which of them to use.

Comment: @Quentin, Yeah, you're right. It all boils down to assignment operators. Have my upvote!